# How to I clear out data for an optional attribute?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsnumber

I have an `NSNumber` that I want to be optional with no default, not have some magic number that represents 'missing' (eg. 0 or -1). ie. on the database I want its value to be a number or null. It starts off at null no problem, but once it gets a number, how can I reset it back to 'missing'?

I have tried:

1. `myAttribute = nil;`
2. `myAttribute = [NSNull null];`
3. `[self setValue:[NSNull null] forKey:@"myAttribute"];`
4. `[self setPrimitiveValue:[NSNull null] forKey:@"myAttribute"];`

The first doesn't crash, but I understand setting a core data attribute to nil is effectively saying it hasn't been fetched. Therefore it doesn't update. The other three crash.

A lot of recommendations suggest that `NSNumber` should always contain a number, so I am not looking for this to be the answer. To get past this, pretend that I am storing data in an `NSString`. How can I get core data to store `NULL` on the database rather than an empty string?

Comment: `setting a core data attribute to nil is effectively saying it hasn't been fetched` ? i never know that, can i have the reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value of an optional attribute to `nil`, there should be no problem with that:

```
self.myAttribute = nil;
[self setValue:nil forKey:@"myAttribute"];
```

both work. Your calls 2, 3, 4 fail because `NSNull` is not a number.

Comment: You're right. I must have had some other code problem causing me to think option 1 was not working.